# How do I left-align the steps to a proof-tree?

Tags: logic, prooftrees

I'm trying to write a natural deduction using LaTeX and the `prooftrees` package which works quite well all things considered. The only issue is that I want my derivation steps to be left-aligned as opposed to center-aligned (which makes sense when I'm doing truth trees, but not so much for ND).

```
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
    \begin{prooftree}
      {
        close with={\ensuremath{\ast}},
      }
      [(A \land B), just=P
        [(A \to C), just=P
            [(B \to D), just=P
                [A, just=(1) Simp.
                    [B, just=(2) Simp.
                        [C, just=(2) MP
                            [D, just=(3) MP
                                [(C \land D), just=(6-7) Conj. Intro.
                                    [\text{QED}, just=\text{1, 2, 3, 8, CP.}]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{prooftree}
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: I don't think `prooftrees` is designed for that kind of natural deduction proof. Does your system have subproofs, and if so, with Fitch style, or Lemmon style, or Kalish-Montague-style, or something else? The LaTeX for logicians site has a [run down of some options](https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/); for K-M style I've used a package called `kmcalc.sty`, which is not on CTAN but I could try to track down if that's what you need. Happy to suggest alternatives if I knew more about your system. You can also just try a table with math-mode auto-applied to the second column.

Comment: As @frabjous says, `prooftrees` really isn't meant for this and you really don't want to use it. It will unnecessarily slow compilation (`prooftrees` is **slow**) and potentially do strange things you don't want. It wouldn't be that hard to make the lines of the proof left-aligned, but you'd be taking on a whole lot of apparatus you don't need.

Comment: @frabjous If you do know where kmcalc.sty can be found, it would be good to know. (I'm not using KM at the moment, so don't worry if it's a bother, but I have done and might again, so if you've tracked it down it would be great if you'd share.)

Comment: @cfr I had a copy saved locally and uploaded it here: [KMcalc.sty](https://people.umass.edu/klement/KMcalc.sty). It says it's in the public domain, so there's no harm in distributing it. But I don't have the documentation, which I think was just on some website I can't even find on the wayback machine. Here's an [old document of mine](https://people.umass.edu/klement/kmcalc-example.tex) that uses it, which might you an idea how to do so, though I define my own commands using its commands rather than using them directly, but it might give you an idea.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks so much! I wonder if it would be worth putting on CTAN as it's PD. So many of these logic packages seem to not make it into the mainstream TeX world and then they just get lost.

Answer (score 2):

*`prooftrees` is not designed for natural deduction proofs in this format. I strongly recommend **not** using it for this purpose. This answer should, therefore, be understood as exploring the implications of counterfactuals rather than exemplifying something in the actual world.*

### ***Caveat emptor ...***

Note that you don't need `\text` in the argument of `just` as these default to text. However, you do need to complete the code in order for the thing to compile and this requires `amstext` for the QED.

I've also deleted your preamble line as you don't have any closed branches in this example and never will have any for any proof of this kind. Closure symbols aren't used in this type of proof.

Note that the final line looks very odd. I wouldn't expect `QED` to be the result of applying a rule of inference but, hey, this is a TeX site and not a logic one, so here goes ...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{prooftrees}

\begin{document}
    
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    wff format={anchor=base west}
  }
  [(A \land B), just=P
    [(A \to C), just=P
        [(B \to D), just=P
            [A, just=(1) Simp.
                [B, just=(2) Simp.
                    [C, just=(2) MP
                        [D, just=(3) MP
                            [(C \land D), just=(6-7) Conj. Intro.
                                [\text{QED}, just={1, 2, 3, 8, CP.}]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image: natural deduction created in a highly non-ideal way]

But, again, there are ***much*** better ways of doing this. This particular format is so straightforward a simple `tabular` would do. For example,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{mylineno}
\setcounter{mylineno}{0}
\newcolumntype{W}{!{\stepcounter{mylineno}(\themylineno)}>{$}l<{$}}
\newenvironment{simpleproof}{\setcounter{mylineno}{0}\begin{tabular}{Wl}}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{simpleproof}
  A \land B & P\\
  A \to C & P\\
  B \to D & P\\
  A & (1) Simp.\\
  B & (1) Simp.\\
  C & (2,4) MP\\
  D & (3,5) MP\\
  (C \land D) & (6,7) Conj.\ Intro.\\
  \text{QED} & (1,2,3,8,CP.)\\
\end{simpleproof}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't implement cross-referencing, as `prooftrees` does, but you don't appear to be using that functionality anyway. If you need to compile more than one or two very simple proofs, something like this will compile *much* faster. `prooftrees` is *s-s-l-l-o-o-o-o-w* because, basically `forest` is slow. `prooftrees` uses various means to speed things up (courtesy of `forest`'s author), but it is still a laborious process. If you need it, I think it's worth it. If you don't need it, you're far better off using something more straightforward.

[image: simple proof with tabular]